# How to determine whether the month is between two dates?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

does anyone know if there is a formula for Google Sheet to check if a specific month (eg, Nov) is present between two dates?

[image: Example]

In the Example above, what formula should I write in cell C2 in order to return a TRUE?

Thanks!

Comment: The details are unclear. November is an entire month. Do you want to know if November 1 falls between the dates? Any part of November? Every single day of the month of November?

Comment: Hi @ErikTyler, it cant be any day in November because the start dates may not overlap - for eg, if I specify 1 November 2020 when the start date is 15 November 2020, it will not take it into account. Thus, only require the month to be November to return TRUE.

Comment: Still not clear. If the start date in A2 is November 2 and the end date is December 2, should C2 be TRUE or FALSE? Next, if the start date in A2 is November 1 and the end date is November 15, should C2 be TRUE or FALSE? Third, if the start date is November 30 and the end date is January 2 of the following year, should C2 be TRUE or FALSE? (Each of these contains PART of "November.")

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=isbetween( month(1 & C1), month(A2), month(B2), false, false )
```

To use inclusive boundaries, use `true` instead of `false`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=IF((MONTH(C1&1)>=MONTH(A2))*(MONTH(C1&1)<=MONTH(B2)); TRUE)
```

[image]