# How to auto-populate if the month is between two dates?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I want to write a formula for auto-populating a column if a month is between two dates.

[image]

So for the example, I would need a formula to put into G3 so that it fills in with all the names that fall in the month of F1 (May) and if the checkbox is ticked in column D then to ignore that name as shown.

Previously I had this where it would only check if the start date matched the month in F1:

[image]

But now I need it to check if the month falls between the dates instead of just the start date.

I was attempting to update this formula with similar logic as the answers in my different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78013551/how-to-find-the-days-that-are-in-a-specific-month-between-two-dates), but I'm not well versed enough in writing formulas to reverse engineer them.

I also found this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67171676/how-to-determine-whether-the-month-is-between-two-dates) but either I'm implementing it wrong or it might not work in a filter since the in-between answer gave a no matches error and the other answer gave a mismatched range error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter(A:A,not(D:D),A:A<>"",regexmatch(F1,map(B:B,C:C,lambda(b,c,if(or(b="",c=""),,join("|",unique(index(text(sequence(c-b+1,1,b),"mmmm")))))))))
```

[image]